# Time Schedule between start and end time

Tags: php

> get start and end time in the data base we need to schedule between start and end time 
>   for example,
>   available time in the database is 3:00-4:00

for we need to schedule time 15 min

so we want to show the time is 3:00-3:15, 3:15-3:30, 3:30-3:45,3:45-4:00

Comment: First of all clearly describe your question

Comment: Add what you have tried so far

Comment: Please post some code. Here we can help you can't code for you....

Comment: Do you want to get the start and end time from db and `echo` it with `15 min` difference? what you tried?

Comment: i am just blank about it, that why i am here for your help

Comment: $selectedTime = "3:00:";
$endTime = strtotime("+15 minutes", strtotime($selectedTime));
echo date('h:i:s', $endTime);

Comment: @RajaS What is the Data Type in your DB is it DateTime or varchar?

Answer (score 0):

I didnt got what you are expecting. But may be this might help you.

```
$time = strtotime('15:00');
$endTime = date("H:i", strtotime('+15 minutes', $time))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $startTime = strtotime("3:00");
    $endTime = strtotime("4:00");

    //call function
    timeInterval($startTime, $endTime);

    function timeInterval($startTime, $endTime) {
        if($startTime < $endTime) {

            $slotTime = date("H:i", strtotime('+15 minutes', $startTime));
            echo date('H:i',$startTime)."-".$slotTime."\n";
            // Resursive function call
            timeInterval(strtotime($slotTime), $endTime);
        }
    }
```

}